# Fractions and Superscript in a table while knitting to docx (RMarkdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable, officer

I have been using officedown for some time now to knit to docx. I encountered an issue where a table I had to create required superscripts in the table as shown below

[image: img]

This led me to go over all the methods for creating a table. Rather than typing it all out here I created an Rmd document below which goes through all the issues. I would be interested in knowing if anyone has any comments or suggestions. My goal is simple. We want a table that exports to docx that

1. Shows up in the list of tables
2. Has a caption
3. In-text reference
4. Shows the fractions correctly

Please find the detailed Rmd with examples [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlH7MwX1yb9APpxn0ifg7DTnpgcAnQL2/view?usp=sharing)

I apologize for the length of the Rmd document but I wanted to showcase in detail what I have attempted to do to facilitate answers and suggestions

**Update:** Got a little roasted on the officer GitHub but it seems that fractions are not possible at the moment but subscripts are using [ftExtra](https://github.com/atusy/ftExtra)